# Set difference from two files in unix

Tags: shell, text-processing, files

I am looking for an efficient way to achieve set difference from 2 files. I do know that `grep -vxF -f setA setB` gives me B - A. This is what I want, but my files are as follows:

```
setA:
2
4
5
6

set B:
1 123
2 abc
3 def
4 hij
```

I want the set difference to be calculated based on the first column of set B; hence the expected output for B - A would be:

```
1 123
3 def
```

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {key[$1]; next} !($1 in key)' setA setB
```

```
1 123
3 def
```

That reads the first file and stores the "ids" in the array "key", then it only prints from the 2nd file if the id is not in the key array.

Answer (score 16):

That's typically what `join` is for:

```
join -v2 setA setB
```

That's joining the files on the first column (which is assumed to be sorted lexically), and print the rows of the second file which are not paired.